# Python serialize Rest and GraphQL the same

Tags: python, rest, serialization, graphql, falconframework

I've been playing with GraphQL (graphene), writing a small Python/Falcon based app which return list of posts, both in Rest & GraphQL:

```
from falcon import API, json
import graphene

def get_all_posts():
    posts = [
        {
            'content': (
                'Hello, '
                "World..."
            ),
            'author': 'Unknown author'
        }
    ]
    return posts


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    posts = graphene.String()

    def resolve_posts(self, info):
        return get_all_posts()


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)

class PostsResource:
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        posts = get_all_posts()
        resp.media = {'posts': json.dumps(posts)}


class GraphQLResource:
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        query = req.params['query']
        result = schema.execute(query)
        resp.media = result.data


api = API()
api.add_route('/graphql', GraphQLResource())
api.add_route('/posts', PostsResource())
```

Querying the **GraphQL** (localhost/graphql?query=query%20posts%20{%20posts%20})

> {"posts": "[{'content': 'Hello, World...', 'author': 'Unknown author'}]"}

and Using the Rest end-point (localhost/posts)

> {"posts": "[{\"content\": \"Hello, World...\", \"author\": \"Unknown author\"}]"}

I'm not sure if that's even important, but I was wondering why It's been serialized differently?.. Does it's even possible to make it the same?

Do it even makes sense to try achieve that?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

- P.S If I'm not dumping (`json.dumps()`) the result in the rest end point I am getting:

> {"posts": [{"content": "Hello, World...", "author": "Unknown author"}]}

Answer (score 0):

looks like it's serializing whole posts list into single string (`posts = graphene.String()`). i'm not too familiar with `graphene` but probrably you have to create nested Schema - something like this:

```
class Post(graphene.ObjectType):
    content = graphene.String()
    author = graphene.String()

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    # or Field instead of List, I'm not sure about that.
    posts = graphene.List(Post)
```

I hope that it will help you move on with your problem